# Install drivers in Linux os

Tags: android, ubuntu, driver

I am Android developer and I need to test my app. I have device moto e5 plus. I am not able to install drivers for that in Ubuntu os.i have checked so many links only found drivers for Windows and Mac. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `sudo apt install adb`

Comment: Normally that works without installing a separate driver.This may help: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux

Comment: you don't need to install any drivers, you just need to edit some file properly to add your device. https://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices